# Hide software keyboard if EditText is not empty

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad, android-input-method

I'm trying to hide the software keyboard when the login activity is loaded with the `EditText` already filled with the `sharedPreferences` data.

I've tried this code found in other questions, but it doesn't work:

```
if(inputEmail.getText().toString().trim() != null){
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputEmail.getWindowToken(),0);
}
```

Can you give me suggestions to resolve this problem?

EDIT: this is my XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!--  View Title Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.37"
            android:background="#900099CC"
            android:text="Registrazione"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--  Email Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email o username" 
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"       
        android:background="#FFF" />

    <!--  Email TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:background="#97FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Password" 
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"       
        android:background="#FFF" />

    <!--  Password TextField -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:background="#97FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkPref"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF"
        android:text="Salva dati di accesso"
        android:checked="true"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <!--  Login Button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="#97000066" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I use the InputMethodManager only in this case when I try to hide the keyboard, please help!

Thank you

EDIT-2: Activity code:

```
public class Login extends Activity 
{
String nomeGiocatore;
Intent intentRegistrazione;
JsonDB jParser = new JsonDB();
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
public static EditText inputEmail;
public static EditText inputPassword;
private CheckBox chkPref;

Editor editor;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Elementi della UI
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    chkPref = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkPref);

    chkPref.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    // utilizzo le sharedpreferences per salvare i dati del login e recuperarli alla successiva apertura dell'app
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 -  private mode
    editor = pref.edit();



    // la tastiera viene nascosta se il campo è già compilato con i dati salvati nelle shared preferences
    if(inputEmail.getText().toString().trim() != "")
    {

        Log.d("KYBRD", "Valor: " + inputEmail.getText().toString().trim());

        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputPassword.getWindowToken(),0);
    }



    inputPassword.setText(pref.getString("password", ""));

    // Salvo il nome del giocatore preso dall'intent registrazione (se si è passati per tale schermata)
    intentRegistrazione = getIntent();
    String username = intentRegistrazione.getStringExtra("nomeGiocatore");

    if(username != null)
    {
        inputEmail.setText(username);
        inputPassword.setText("");

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
    else
        inputEmail.setText(pref.getString("name", ""));

    // Override del bottone, in modo che funzioni da "tasto Invio"
    inputPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || 
                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
            {
                new CheckUser(Login.this,inputEmail.getText().toString().trim(),inputPassword.getText().toString().trim()).execute();
            }

            if (chkPref.isChecked())
            {
                editor.putString("name", inputEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.putString("password", inputPassword.getText().toString().trim());

                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    inputPassword.setImeActionLabel("Invia", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

    // Override del metodo onClick per controllare la presenza della connessione, 
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            // controllo se esiste una connessione

            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Login.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            Boolean isWifiConnected = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
            Boolean isMobileConnected = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();

            if(!isWifiConnected && !isMobileConnected)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)
                .setTitle("Connessione non attiva!")
                .setMessage("Per giocare a ProjectM è necessaria la connessione alla rete. Vuoi andare alla pagina delle impostazioni?")
                .setNegativeButton("Attiva Wifi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Attiva rete mobile", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();
            }
            else
            {
                // Verifico correttezza dati login
                new CheckUser(Login.this,inputEmail.getText().toString().trim(),inputPassword.getText().toString().trim()).execute();

                if (chkPref.isChecked())
                {
                    editor.putString("name", inputEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                    editor.putString("password", inputPassword.getText().toString().trim());

                    editor.commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Override del metodo onClick che porta alla schermata di registrazione
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Intent intentToRegistration = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Register.class);
            startActivity(intentToRegistration);
            finish();
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

Here is the code, hope it helps you!

Comment: Are you forcing showing the softkeyboard elsewhere? I think it shouldn't appear by itself.

Comment: show the value in logcat after trimmin

Comment: I added a "not" to your question as it seems you have missed it (otherwise it would mean the complete opposite of your question main text)

Comment: @zozelfelfo I checked, but neither in xml or java code I forced the keyboard to appear..

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to hide keyboard? Could you post your activity code as well ?

Comment: @PawelCala added code just now!

Comment: @TheCondor I edited my previous solution. Now it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your hide keyboard code with this line:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

It will help now.

Cheers

Comment: The conditional is working, I've tested it. I think that the problem is in the InputMethodManager, but I can't figure it out..

Answer (score 1):

for hiding soft keyboard try to use :

```
/**
     * Hides Soft Keyboard displayed by currently focused EditText
     * 
     * @param pEditText EditText currenly focused EditText
     */
    protected void hideSoftKeyboard( EditText pEditText )
    {
        InputMethodManager lInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) pEditText.getContext().getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );
        lInputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow( pEditText.getWindowToken() , 0 );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if result of `trim()` is an empty string, not `null`

Comment: if I print the variable value in Logcat, is an empty string. I changed the conditional to ' something != "" ' but it doesn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" to hide keyboard

Comment: it doesn't work for me, as you see I've added it in the edited question but it has no effect..